# How to install Gyachi on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation

ok ... there is no way to install it on ubuntu 12.10

I would like to use Gyachi on ubuntu 12.10. I tried these steps but it doesn't work..
I wanted to compile it myself... but it need some libs... it made me confused... so I gave up

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adilson/experimental
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gyachi
```

Thank you for your helps
at first command the output:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adilson/experimental
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Contains packages that are not in the official Debian/Ubuntu repositories and newer versions and snapshots which are not available yet in the repositories. Theses packages are experimental. Use them at your own risk.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~adilson/+archive/experimental
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp3y3i7p/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp3y3i7p/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 27B81625 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp3y3i7p/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 27B81625: public key "Launchpad Experimental Packages PPA" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

and after sudo apt-get update;

this is (sudo apt-get install gyachi)'s output
here is the output:

```
sudo apt-get install gyachi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gyachi
```

Comment: We need the *exact* error to help you. A question saying "it doesn't work" is very difficult to rectify. Please add the error by editing your post.

Comment: the error is " E: Unable to locate package gyachi
 "

Comment: Are you sure you have the right PPA? Does the first and second command succeed? Can oyou give the output of the first and second commands?

Comment: es I am sure. I used these instarctions here is http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-gyachi-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty-using-ppa.html

Comment: Can you give the output of the first two commands? Copy-paste it exactly.

Comment: I edited as you wish :)

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~adilson/+archive/experimental doesn't show Gyachi for quantal. So no use by adding the PPA

Comment: oh I got it... I thought there is a way to install it.. I wanted to compile it myself... but it need some libs... it made me confused... so I gave up

Comment: Gyachi hasn't been added to that repository for Ubuntu 12.10 yet but I wouldn't be surprised if it is added in the near future. Keep checking back.

Comment: I would enjoy using empathy or pidgin but neither of those provide webcam for Yahoo and I like seeing my grandchildren when I chat with them.
So gyachi is the only option

Answer (score 1):

Gyachi is no longer maintained, and will be rather difficult to install on current versions of Ubuntu/Linux in general. You would be better off using Empathy or Pidgin.